# How to get the file's MIME type for box.com v2 java api

Tags: box-api

I am trying to integrate my webapp with Box.com using (Box Api java V2) and need the ability to download the selected files and folders from Box.com onto my server. I am able to easily do this, but not able to get file's mime-type from the Box api.

In my application, I also store the MIME type of the files. Is it possible to directly get the Mime type of a file using Box Java Api v2?

Thanks,
Gala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Box doesn't currently expose MIME types.  You can view a list of the available [File object](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-file-object) properties.

Comment: thanks for that - atleast it stops me from hunting for it.. Though it would be desirable of Box to give out the MimeType

Comment: any change? Is this the _only_ service that doesn't give out MIME types?

Comment: also curious if this is ever going to get some attention? are mime types on the road map or just a "Don't fix" ?

Comment: You might look into using file [metadata](https://docs.box.com/reference#metadata-object) as a way to associate a MIME type with a file. ("Don't fix" presumes the API is broken; this is simply a feature it has never supported.)